# Strugglin with jquery rotate animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, rotation

I'm strugglin with the jquery animation. i have two `li` tags the first is just like a divider and the second is the link. if the user hovers the second, the first should be rotate 90 degrees. The html looks like this:

```
<div id="navbar">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="divider"><i id="oneTh" class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up fa-rotate-270"></i><li>
    <li class="active"><a id="one" class="th-ho" href="#">Leistungen</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

But if i test it the divider rotate 90 degrees to fast and then it rotates again 90 degrees, that after the whole animation it rotates in sum 180 degrees.

Here the javascript:

```
function rotateThumbIcon() {
    $('.th-ho').hover(function() {
        var thId = '#' + this.id + 'Th';

        $(thId).animateRotate(90, 1000, "linear", function(){
            console.log(this); //this is supposed to be the DOM node, but it isn't
        });
    });
}

$.fn.animateRotate = function(angle, duration, easing, complete) {
    var args = $.speed(duration, easing, complete);
    var step = args.step;
    return this.each(function(i, e) {
        args.step = function(now) {
            $.style(e, 'transform', 'rotate(' + now + 'deg)');
            if (step) return step.apply(this, arguments);
        };

        $({deg: 0}).animate({deg: angle}, args);
    });
};
```

Here the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/r293oLdg/

Any suggestions? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you also want to rotate it back if you're not over the link? Or only the 90 degree rotation?

Comment: Yes, i want to rotate back if the user leave the li

Comment: `.hover(fn)` is equivalent to `.hover(fn, fn)` - ie fn() is called on mouseover and mouseout. I don't fully understand what's going on in the plugin but it looks over-complex for the task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could accomplish the same thing using css. It is rotating 360 degrees, because fa-rotate-270 is already rotated 270 degrees.  Snippet below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.th-ho').mouseenter(function() {
        $('.fa-thumbs-o-up').addClass('onhover');
    });
    $('.th-ho').mouseleave(function() {
        $('.fa-thumbs-o-up').removeClass('onhover');
    });
});
```

```css
.fa-thumbs-o-up.onhover {
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(360deg);
}
.fa-thumbs-o-up {
    -moz-transition: all 1s linear;    /* Firefox */
    -webkit-transition: all 1s linear; /* WebKit */
    -o-transition: all 1s linear; /* Opera */
    transition: all 1s linear;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="navbar">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="divider"><i id="oneTh" class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up fa-rotate-270"></i><li>
        <li class="active"><a id="one" class="th-ho" href="#">Leistungen</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you only want this to happen once whenever you hover over the link, you could use the "mouseenter" instead of the "hover" event.
As follows:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  rotateThumbIcon();
});

function rotateThumbIcon() {
  $('.th-ho').mouseenter(function() {
    var thId = '#' + this.id + 'Th';

    $(thId).animateRotate(90, 1000, "linear", function() {
      console.log(e); //this is supposed to be the DOM node, but it isn't
    });
  });
  $('.th-ho').mouseleave(function() {
    var thId = '#' + this.id + 'Th';

    $(thId).animateRotate(0, 1000, "linear", function() {
      console.log(e); //this is supposed to be the DOM node, but it isn't
    });
  });
}

$.fn.animateRotate = function(angle, duration, easing, complete) {
  var args = $.speed(duration, easing, complete);
  var step = args.step;
  return this.each(function(i, e) {
    args.step = function(now) {
      $.style(e, 'transform', 'rotate(' + now + 'deg)');
      if (step) return step.apply(this, arguments);
    };

    $({
      deg: 0
    }).animate({
      deg: angle
    }, args);
  });
};
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="navbar">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="divider"><i id="oneTh" class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up fa-rotate-270"></i>
    </li>
    <li class="active"><a id="one" class="th-ho" href="#">Leistungen</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: It is still rotating 180 degrees - once from
`$.style(e, 'transform', 'rotate(' + now + 'deg)');`
and once from
`$({deg: 0}).animate({deg: angle}, args);`
You don't need both these statements.

Comment: I think there's a problem with fa-rotate-270. I've removed it and added a -90 degree rotation instead of 270 degree. Then you can rotate from -90 to 0. I've changed the code a bit and I'm using a css class to do the rotation. See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/r293oLdg/5/)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    rotateThumbIcon();
});

function rotateThumbIcon() {
    var elem = $(".th-ho");
    var thId = $("#" + elem[0].id + "Th");        
    elem.hover(function() {      
        thId.animateRotate(0, 1000, "linear", function(){
            console.log(this); 
        });
    }, function() {
        thId.animateRotate(-90, 1000, "linear", function() {
          console.log("complete");
        })
    });
}

$.fn.animateRotate = function(angle, duration, easing, complete) {
    var args = $.speed(duration, easing, complete);
    args.step = function(now) {
            $(this).css("transform", "rotate(" + now + "deg)");
        };
    $(this).animate({deg: angle}, args);
};
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/r293oLdg/6/

Answer (score 0):

@Marios Hadjimichael beat me to the answer.

Hover expects 2 function arguments but you're only using 1.
Jquery seems to be using the one function for both enter and exit.   mouseenter only happens when the mouse enters the element and only requires 1 function argument.   Seems the logical choice.